# Pass in part of a parameter into security.yml - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have this in parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    various_info:
        setting_1:
            test: true
```

I want to pass in 'various_info.setting_1' into a service, but can only seem to get it working if I pass in the whole 'various_info' parameter.

In services.yml this would work

```
a.random.service:
    class: etc..
    arguments:
        - @another_service
        - %another_param%
        - %various_info%
```

...but I want to just pass in the part required, and neither of these will work

```
arguments:
    - %various_info.setting_1%
arguments:
    - [%various_info.setting_1%]
```

Is it possible? It would be clearner and a better practice to only pass the part required I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. The security.yml gets included at the beginning of config.yml, which also includes the parameters.yml.